# SQL joining a table containing multiple/duplicate values, to both fields on a table that is 1 to 1

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Oracle DB

Table1 looks like so, it is strictly one to one, no duplicates...

```
Row   Primary   Secondary
--------------------------------
1     1     2
2     3     4
3     5     6
```

Table2 has the corresponding IDs with multiple names for each.

```
ID      Name
------------------------
1       Server1
2       Server2
3       Server3
3       Server4
3       Server5
4       Server6
4       Server7
5       Server8
6       Server9
6       Server10
```

Now, this is what I am doing right now, simplified...

```
Select  t1.row row,
       t2.name p_name,
       t2a.name s_name
From table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.primary = t2.id
left join table2 t2a on t1.secondary = t2a.id
```

this gives me a result like this, which I know is correct for the code I used..

```
Row p_name      s_name
-------------------------------
1   Server1     Server2
2   Server3     Server6
2   Server3     Server7
2   Server4     Server6
2   Server4     Server7
2   Server5     Server6
2   Server5     Server7
3   Server8     Server9
3   Server8     Server10
```

What I want, and cannot figure out how to do... is get this result:

```
Row   p_name    s_name
-------------------------------
1     Server1   Server2
2     Server3   Server6
2     Server4   Server7
2     Server5   null
3     Server8   Server9
3     null      Server10
```

In essence... I want to be able to pair up values from a 1 to 1 relationship, where there could be 1, 2, 3 or more for each value, but I don't want all the combinations, just the 1, 2 or 3, and then the other set of 1, 2 or 3, and a null value for the numbers are no equal.  I am obviously new to SQL and have searched around, I just can't figure out what to try next.

Comment: Why do you have multiple values for the same ID ? This looks like a poorly designed database..!

Comment: First, that database is part of an application.  It's kind of irrelevent... but it's because you have standalone servers and clusters of servers linked as primary and standby or DR.  They also have unique IDs, but the "pairing" is such that it has to incorporate assigning a group of 3 to a group of 2.  How else would you go about it, other than group1 = server 1, server2, server3 to group2 = server 4, server 5.

Comment: whther a poor database design is part of an application is irrelevant, it is still a poor design. You don't have these problems when you take the time to properly design your database. You do not havea way to proerly tell whcih is the name you want for teh scondary server as you did not store teh information correctly.

Comment: i don't understand why you would think you can judge a database by a fictional representation of a custom view created by me.  The database has 100s of tables.  one table is for items, there are 100s of thousands of items, with 100s of item types.  there is a table for millions of properties for these items and a table for millions of connections for items.  i made a custom view which contains all servers, which came from 2 different types of items, single servers, and clusters of servers.  The application stores data as needed.  I am trying to make a report how i want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another join conditions that is a sequence number.  Fortunately, you can get this using `row_number()`.  This is quite close to what you want:

```
Select t1.row as row,
       t2.name as p_name,
       t2a.name as s_name
From table1 t1 left join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (partition by t2.id order by t2.id) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.primary = t2.id left join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (partition by t2.id order by t2.id) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2a
      on t1.secondary = t2a.id and t2.seqnum = t2a.seqnum;
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't handle the situation where the second list is longer than the first.  I think this should work:

```
Select t1.row as row,
       t2.name as p_name,
       t2a.name as s_name
From table1 t1 left join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (partition by t2.id order by t2.id) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.primary = t2.id full outer join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (partition by t2.id order by t2.id) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2a
      on t1.secondary = t2a.id and t2.seqnum = t2a.seqnum;
```

Comment: Beat me to it. And nice catch on the second list being longer than the first!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`rank()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions123.htm) function to create an "order" in the duplicate names, and then use it as part of your join condition:

```
SELECT    t1.row, 
          primary_names.name AS p_name,
          secondary_names.name AS s_name
FROM      table1 t1
JOIN      (SELECT id, name, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id ASC) AS rk
           FROM   table2) primary_names 
          ON t1.primary = primary_names.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, name, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id ASC) AS rk
           FROM   table2) secondary_names 
          ON t1.secondary = secondary_names.id AND 
             primary_names.rk = secondary_names.rk
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the wrong data model. You are trying to establish a relationship between Table1 and Table2.

If you were to add a foreign key constraint on Table1 for this relationship, the database wouldn't allow you, because an FK must always point to a Primary Key on the referenced table. If you were to try to add a PK on Table2 on the ID column, the database also wouldn't allow you, because the values on this column are not unique.

Review your data model. After that, your code should look like this:

```
        create table t2 (id number, name varchar2(10), 
        constraint t2PK primary key (id));

        create table t1 (nrow number, prim number, sec number, 
        constraint fkPrim foreign key (prim) references t2(id), 
        constraint fkSec foreign key (sec) references t2(id));

        insert into t2 values (1,       'Server1');
        insert into t2 values (2,       'Server2');
        insert into t2 values (3,       'Server3');
        insert into t2 values (4,       'Server7');
        insert into t2 values (5,       'Server8');
        insert into t2 values (6,       'Server9');

        insert into t1 values (1,     1,     2);
        insert into t1 values (2,     3,     4);
        insert into t1 values (3,     5,     6);
        commit;



        Select  t1.nrow nrow,
               t2a.name p_name,
               t2b.name s_name
        From  t1
        left join  t2 t2a on t1.prim = t2a.id
        left join  t2 t2b on t1.sec = t2b.id;

      NROW P_NAME     S_NAME    
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Server1    Server2   
         2 Server3    Server7   
         3 Server8    Server9
```